# Crear un nuevo dataframe a partir de un dataframe, pero con las columnas que yo necesite

Tags: r, rstudio

buen día, requiero saber como puedo guardar un nuevo dataframe seleccionando la columna identificación, edad y resultados exámenes

```
Identificación |  Nombre |      Apellidos       | Resultados examenes | Edad |
1145667789     | Marcelo |   Ramirez Bedolla    |         5.0         |  23  |
```

Salida esperada

```
Identificación | Resultados examenes | Edad |
1145667789     |         5.0         |  23  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La selección de columnas de un `data.frame` con R base puede realizarse de varias formas:

###### 1. Por el número de la columna

```
df[,c(1,4,5)]
```

###### 2. Por el nombre

```
df[,c("Identificación", "Resultados examenes", "Edad")]
```

###### 3. Indicando mediante valores lógicos la columna a seleccionar

```
df[, c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)]
```

###### 4. Usando `subset()` sin filtro

```
subset(df, ,c("Identificación", "Resultados examenes", "Edad"))
```

No importa la forma que uses, en todos los casos se genera un nuevo `data.frame`, solo tendrás que asignar el resultado a una nueva variable para poder acceder a estos nuevos datos.

Answer (score 1):

También podrías usar el paquete `dplyr` y quedaría así

```
library(dplyr)

df2 = df1 %>%
   select(Identificación, "Resultados examenes", Edad)
```

A mi en particular me gusta mucho esta librería por la facilidad que tiene.